# Thymeleaf loads CSS but not Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot app with a Thymeleaf template, that is supposed to load a css file and a javascript file. 
The CSS file loads, but the Javascript file doesnt, it does not even try to get it from the server. There is no HTTP request for the Javascript, but the requests for the CSS are visible.
Where is my mistake?

I already tried putting the link for the javascript in the header next to the css but that made no difference.

My folder structure is as follows:

```html
resources
-- static
---- bootstrap
------ css
---- js
```

Here the HTML:

```html
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org" lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Website Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_custom.css}" />
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <script th:href="@{/js/main.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error message, the  tag for the javascript is simply ignored.

Comment: what does your script contain?
Try to put some console.log in your script and check your dev tools console

Comment: Found the error: I wrote script th:href instead of th:src. A overdue nap has brought the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag should read

```
<script th:src[...]>
```

instead of

```
<script th:href[...]>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script end tag is incomplete.  It should be:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/main.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Found the error: I wrote script th:href instead of th:src.